# Enabling browser to begin rendering initial pages quickly on large PDF files

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iis, webforms

My application currently allows direct links to PDF files on the server, but the files now need to be secured and direct links will have to be phased out because of security concerns.

I have tried the following lines to send PDF file to the client.  It works fine.

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
        Response.WriteFile(filepath);
        Response.End();
```

But there is a catch.

When a PDF file is linked, the browser renders the first few pages right away while downloading the rest.  But with the approach above, the browser waits until the entire file has been downloaded and then proceeds to render the PDF.

So is there a way to trick the browser into mimicking opening a directly linked PDF?

Answer (score 0):

After reading your post I realized my application had the same behavior (although given the typical sizes of files and the formats used it hasn't been an issue - at least not yet...)  Upon some research, you'll have to choose from a couple of options depending upon how much complexity you want to introduce:

If you want a simpler implementation, you'll need to change your approach a bit to set up a loop that reads a certain amount of the file into a buffer in memory and then performs a `Response.Write` for that buffer.  In the loop you'd then do a `Response.Flush` to push that data towards the client.  Since this is synchronous, you'll have to wait until the flush is complete before you can push down the next block of the file.  But, if the primary goal is getting the first couple of blocks out there so they client application can begin working with them, this might meet your needs.

If you want potentially better server-side scalability and are willing to accept a bit more complexity, you'll need to explore using `Response.BeginFlush`.  I believe asynchronous writing was introduced in .Net 4.5. Here's a link that should get you started:

http://www.slideshare.net/pragyanshis/asynchronous-reading-and-writing-http-r-equest

I'm adding exploring both approaches to my "to do" list for my own application...

Comment: I tried that approach, but the browser does not behave any differently.  It still waits for the whole file to download before rendering.

Comment: Have you tried this across multiple browsers and experienced the same behavior?

Comment: One thing I just noticed is that you do not appear to set `Response.BufferOuput` (or the deprecated `Response.Buffer`) to `False`. Have you done this and does that improve the user's experience?

Comment: I tried setting Response.BufferOutput to false.  Makes no difference.  I also tried this on multiple browsers and got the same result.  They all wait for the transmission of the entire file before rendering the PDF.

Comment: Hmmm....another thought: have you recently changed web server software versions or their associated configurations that might be impacting how the data can flows from apps out to the client?  I'm beginning to wonder if this is somehow an IIS configuration issue.